# Split vector at unknown index

Tags: r, vector, indexing, split

I have a vector in R which contains at least 50.000 reals.
The values are ordered from small to large and now I need to split up this vector in different vectors. The vector has to be split up when the difference between two numbers is larger than a given number (say two).

Example,

```
data <- c(1,1.1, 1.2, 4, 4.2, 8, 8.9, 9, 9.3);
# Then I need the following vectors:
x1 <- c(1, 1.1, 1.2);
x2 <- c(4, 4.2);
x3 <- c(8, 8.9, 9, 9.3);
```

The difficulty is that we don't know the number of needed vectors and don't know the length of each vector at forehand.

Now I have the following idea, however this is very time consuming and it is only able to split the vector into two new vectors.

```
j <- 2;
seqDemA1 <- seqDemandA[1];
while((seqDemandA[j-1] - seqDemandA[j] < 2) && (j < length(seqDemandA)+1)) {
    seqDemA1 <- c(seqDemA1, seqDemandA[j]);
    j <- j+1;
}
seqDemA2 <- seqDemandA[j];
j <- j+1;
while((seqDemandA[j-1] - seqDemandA[j] < 2) && (j < length(seqDemandA)+1)) {
    seqDemA2 <- c(seqDemA2, seqDemandA[j]);
    j <- j+1;
}
```

I'm looking forward for your help!

Comment: What is supposed to happen when you find multiple possible split points (ie there are multiple points where the difference between successive numbers is greater than 2)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this,

```
split(data, cumsum(c(0, diff(data)>=2)))
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, great!
Never thought it should be that easy.

Furthermore, I had to split another vector at the same indeces. The simple solution:

y1 <- split(x, cumsum(c(0, diff(x)>=2)));
y2 <- split(z, cumsum(c(0, diff(x)>=2)));